# Why is $mg$ split into components instead of the tension in vertical uniform circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, vectors, free-body-diagram

I am a beginner physics student.

I am trying to prove that the magnitude of the tension varies sinusoidally as an object P travels around the circle or something of that sort. Thus, I am evaluating the tension at certain points, or a general $\theta$. I am trying to solve for the tension in terms of the other variables, but when I split the tension into components, I got non-customary results. After some research, I found that $mg$ is to be split into components instead of the tension. Why so?

It seems that as the object undergoes vertical uniform circular motion, the tension's direction changes, while $mg$ does not. How come when solving for tension when there is an angle, mg is split into components instead of the tension? In a horizontal uniform circular motion, the tension was split into components, but what caused the change in the variable being split into components?

[image]

Also, [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/cirvert.html) it says that the tension at the bottom is $6mg$ more than the tension at the top. Shouldn't it only be a difference of $2mg$, because the tension at the top is $m(\frac{v^2}{r}+g)$ while the tension at the bottom is $m(\frac{v^2}{r}-g)$?

An example for reference:

[image]

Image source: [here](http://dev.physicslab.org/document.aspx?doctype=3&filename=oscillatorymotion_verticalcircles.xml)

Comment: Please provide a clear example of vertical uniform circular motion and horizontal uniform circular motion, as the choice of which vectors to resolve into components is usually context dependent.

Comment: I have added an example to which I am referring too.

Comment: Actually, why is the velocity twice as much at the bottom? Should it not be sqrt(3)? The kinetic energy gained during the journey from top to bottom is the potential energy lost, which is 2mgR, and using the equation linking gR and v_top, you find that the added kinetic energy plus the kinetic energy it had at the top will lead to thrice the kinetic energy it had originally, and thus the velocity should increase by a factor of sqrt(3). (Since at the bottom no potential energy is stored.)

Comment: I mean sqrt(5). Using energy balance, and also the equation for instantaneous centripetal acceleration, I find that no matter what, the speed on the bottom should be sqrt(5) times the speed at the top. (I cannot edit the comment.) But this example says it was twice as fast at the bottom - I don't see this come out as dependent on the radius or anything, and I don't get two as the factor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider conservation of energy:
$$E_{kin}^{top}+E_{pot}^{top} = E_{kin}^{bottom}+E_{pot}^{bottom}$$
You can then solve for e.g. the velocity of the mass at the top and then
compare the forces you obtain:
$$|F_{top}|= \dfrac{mv_{top}^2}{r} - mg\qquad\text{and} \qquad |F_{bottom}| = \dfrac{mv_{bottom}^2}{r} + mg$$
I think you can figure it out from there, good luck.

Edit: why does only the $mg$ part split into components? Remember that forces are actually vector quantities, i.e. have a direction, then think about which direction the gravitational force has and which the centripetal force has.

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate a little the last part where you remark about the direction of gravitation force and centripetal force? I understand that gravity acts downwards, and that the centripetal force can have more than one component, but I am still confused.

Comment: Both forces have 3 components, if you choose an appropriate coordinate system, in this case z-axis pointing 'up', then some vectors may only point in the direction of one of your axis, e.g. $\vec{F}_G=-mg\hat{e}_z$. The centripetal force on the other hand always points to the center of rotation. The tension of a string is defined as the magnitude of forces 'pulling' on it. Since shearing forces (i.e. forces acting orthogonal to the string) don't pull on the string, they don't contribute to the tension.

Comment: Thanks! Could I also say that because the magnitude of the tension is always changing, it is better to split $mg$ into components because it stays constant?

Comment: Let me rehrease that: when analyzing the tension in vertical uniform motion by using a free body diagram, it is better to split $mg$ into components instead of the tension because the magnitude and direction of the tension vary, while $mg$ stays the same. Is this right?

Comment: @user275102 It seems to be that because you are using the equation for centripetal acceleration here, you want to split your forces into radial (along the centripetal acceleration direction) vs tangential, as opposed to vertical (the direction mg points) vs horizontal. So you split up the vertical force into radial and tangential components. If you were working with some formula or force or formulation that was more convenient to do in a horizontal/vertical direction, you would split up the tension into these two components instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Above picture contains tension as a sinusoidal function which varies with $\theta$.
As you can see, v is the velocity that we impart for the motion to take place and v1 is the velocity at an angle $\theta$. Using energy conservation we can find T(Tension).

> It seems that as the object undergoes vertical uniform circular motion, the tension's direction changes, while mg
> does not. How come when solving for tension when there is an angle, mg is split into components instead of the tension?

You can split tension also into respective components, but it would be lengthy as centripetal force does not act along Mg. Why we resolve mg into components? because it is easy for us to equate it to centripetal force and solve the problem quickly.

One way you can go about it is that, you can resolve tension along Mg and perpendicular to Mg, find the vector sum of all these forces and finally resolve them in the direction of centripetal force. You would still get the same answer.

> Also, here it says that the tension at the bottom is 6mg
> more than the tension at the top. Shouldn't it only be a difference of 2mg
> , because the tension at the top is $m(\frac{v^2}{r}+g)$
> while the tension at the bottom is $m(\frac{v^2}{r}-g)$
> ?

We do not calculate centripetal force as such. Centripetal force is just the vector sum of the forces acting towards the centre of the circle. At the top Both tension and mg act downwards, thus vector sum of them is $T + mg$ which equals the centripetal force.
$$ T + mg = m\frac{v^2}{r} $$
$$ T_{Top} = m\frac{v^2}{r} - mg $$
Similarly for bottom
$$ T_{Bottom} = m\frac{v^2}{r} + mg $$
Hope this Answered your question.